# Play Games Services Achievements not work

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console

I added achievements to my game. 
Problems:
If I get an achievement it works (it shows +0 XP ) but reset. So it looks like server ignore it.
In Google API Console I see many errors:

- time,games
- 2020-06-12T10:49:19.359Z,1
- 2020-06-12T21:37:19.359Z,1
- 2020-06-14T09:37:19.359Z,0.782608695652174

I found report "errors by method". It is too big, so it looks like:

- time,games.achievementDefinitions.list,games.achievements.increment,games.achievements.list,games.achievements.unlock,games.achievements.updateMultiple,games.applications.played,games.players.get,games.scores.list,games.scores.listWindow,games.scores.submitMultiple
- 2020-05-28T10:33:07.231Z,0,,,,,0,0,,,
- 2020-05-28T17:45:07.231Z,0,,0,0,0,0.16071428571428573,0,,,
- 2020-05-28T21:21:07.231Z,0,,0,0,0,0,0,,,

But how I can use it?
I checked [troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting) and find nothing to help.

GoogleSignInApi is works.
Code after sign in:

```
GamesClient gc = Games.getGamesClient( activity, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount( activity ) );
gc.setViewForPopups( activity.findViewById(R.id.root) );
gc.setGravityForPopups( Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL );

//achievements
AchievementsClient ac = Games.getAchievementsClient( activity, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount( activity ) );
ac.unlockImmediate( activity.getString(R.string.achievement_first ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.
Problem: I created in Google API Console two auth2 keys: debug and next release.
It was working for debug only but you can log in.
If you delete the second key you can not edit the first, so I recreate whole game.
There is no information in documentation and you can add two or more keys.